# Iconic LiveTile push notification via php results in PayloadFormatError

Tags: php, push-notification, windows-phone-8, live-tile, mpns

Final **EDIT** working code (Huge thanks to Claus for taking time and solving it):

```php
class WindowsPhonePushDelay
{
    const Immediate=0;
    const In450Sec=10;
    const In900Sec=20;
}

class WindowsPhonePushNotification
{
    private $notif_url = '';

    function WindowsPhonePushNotification($notif_url)
    {
        $this->notif_url = $notif_url;
    }

    public function send_raw($msg,$message_id=NULL, $delay = WindowsPhonePushDelay::Immediate)
    {
        return $this->send_push(NULL,$delay+3,$message_id, $msg);
    }

    public function send_normal_tile($image_url, $title, $count,$message_id=NULL, $delay = WindowsPhonePushDelay::Immediate)
    {
        $msg =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
                "<wp:Tile>" .
                "<wp:BackgroundImage>$image_url</wp:BackgroundImage>" .
                "<wp:Count>$count</wp:Count>" .
                "<wp:Title>$title</wp:Title>" .
                "</wp:Tile>" .
                "</wp:Notification>";
                return $this->send_push('token',$delay+1, $message_id,$msg);
    }
       public function send_iconic_tile($image_url_large, $image_url_small, $wide1, $wide2, $wide3, $title, $count,$message_id=NULL, $delay = WindowsPhonePushDelay::Immediate)
    {
        $msg =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\" Version=\"2.0\">" .
                "<wp:Tile Id=\"\" Template=\"IconicTile\">" .
                "<wp:SmallIconImage>$image_url_small</wp:SmallIconImage>" .
                "<wp:IconImage>$image_url_large</wp:IconImage>" .
                "<wp:WideContent1>$wide1</wp:WideContent1>" .
                "<wp:WideContent2>$wide2</wp:WideContent2>" .
                "<wp:WideContent3>$wide3</wp:WideContent3>" .
                "<wp:Count>$count</wp:Count>" .
                "<wp:Title>$title</wp:Title>" .
                "<wp:BackgroundColor>#00FFFFFF</wp:BackgroundColor>" .
                "</wp:Tile>" .
                "</wp:Notification>";
       echo $msg;
    return $this->send_push('token',$delay+1, $message_id,$msg);
    }

    public function send_toast($title, $message,$message_id=NULL, $delay = WindowsPhonePushDelay::Immediate)
    {
        $msg =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
                "<wp:Toast>" .
                "<wp:Text1>$title</wp:Text1>" .
                "<wp:Text2>$message</wp:Text2>" .
                "</wp:Toast>" .
                "</wp:Notification>";

        return $this->send_push('toast',$delay+2,$message_id, $msg);
    }

    private function send_push($target,$delay,$message_id,$msg)
    {
        $sendedheaders=  array(
                            'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 ',
                            'Accept: application/*',
                            "X-NotificationClass: $delay"
                            );
        if($message_id!=NULL)
        $sendedheaders[]="X-MessageID: $message_id";
        if($target!=NULL)
            $sendedheaders[]="X-WindowsPhone-Target:$target";

        $req = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$sendedheaders);
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg);
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_URL, $this->notif_url);
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($req);
        curl_close($req);

        $result=array();
        foreach(explode("\n",$response) as $line)
        {

        $tab=explode(":",$line,2);
        if(count($tab)==2)
            $result[$tab[0]]=trim($tab[1]);
        }

        return $result;
     }
}
```

**EDIT**: The XML (tried with both local image and remote image)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification" Version="2.0"><wp:Tile Id="/" Template="IconicTile"><wp:SmallIconImage Action="Clear">/Images/LiveTiles/asot_iconic_small.png</wp:SmallIconImage><wp:IconImage Action="Clear">/Images/LiveTiles/asot_iconic_large.png</wp:IconImage><wp:WideContent1 Action="Clear">Test1</wp:WideContent1><wp:WideContent2 Action="Clear">Test2</wp:WideContent2><wp:WideContent3 Action="Clear">Test3</wp:WideContent3><wp:Count Action="Clear">1</wp:Count><wp:Title Action="Clear">Title</wp:Title><wp:BackgroundColor Action="Clear">#00FFFFFF</wp:BackgroundColor></wp:Tile></wp:Notification>
```

EDIT2 Full error msg:

```
"The XML payload contains invalid or improperly formatted XML or the notification type specified in the header does not match the payload type used.  The channel has been closed.  Check your XML payload for errors and reopen the channel to obtain a new URI."
```

EDIT3 Server response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-DeviceConnectionStatus: Connected X-NotificationStatus: Received X-SubscriptionStatus: Active X-MessageID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ActivityId: 5bd4c4b6-1d79-4964-9a56-7d49e2aa5972 X-Server: DB3MPNSM018 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2012 19:35:59 GMT Content-Length: 0
```

I'm using the above code (made by Rudy Huyn) when trying to send a Push Notification. It works fine with sending a normal tile but I'm trying to update my app so it can receive a iconic tile instead. I've added the send_iconic_tile myself.

However when I'm sending an iconic tile notification I'm getting a PayloadFormatError on the phone. I can't see any error in my code either since the payload seems to match what Microsoft has written here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your payload is indeed invalid.

The `BackgroundColor` needs to be in HEX format of `#FF000000` (`00FFFFFF` for Transparent), and the `Id="/"` should be `Id=""`.

Remember there can't be any whitespaces before or after the hex value for the background color.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however still getting the same error. I've updated the code above with the utf-16 encoding but it didn't seem to do the trick... It should stil be the same headers if I understand correctly?

Comment: Have you verified that your XML isn't malformed? Try print it out, and then verify. If you can add a printed example of your XML to the question, I'll verify it directly using the `PushUpdateTile` API call (partner restricted API)

Comment: The background colour needs to be in the format of `#00FFFFFF` and not `Transparent`.

Comment: Oh, and there's a bug in your `Id` field, `Id="/"` needs to be `Id=""`.

Comment: Still same old error. Added the ms-server response to original post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19239/discussion-between-claus-jorgensen-and-robertftw)