# Payload error while using PHP to update live tiles windows phone 8

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I'm having problems updating my live tiles using PHP via Push Notifications.  For normal Toast Message there wasn't any error.  But when I tried using the same coding, and change the phone target as well as the notification class.  I got a payload error.  Here's my source code, and wondering if I did something wrong.

Thanks!

```
<?php
   if( isset($_POST['push_action']) && $_POST['push_action'] == "1") {
   $tileMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
                   "<wp:Tile>" .
                    "<wp:BackgroundImage>" . $_POST["push_msg0"] . 
"</wp:BackgroundImage>" +
                    "<wp:Count>" . $_POST["push_msg1"] . "</wp:Count>" +
                    "<wp:Title>" . $_POST["push_msg2"] . "</wp:Title>" +
                    "<wp:BackBackgroundImage>" . $_POST["push_msg3"] . "</wp:BackBackgroundImage>" +
                    "<wp:BackTitle>" . $_POST["push_msg4"] . "</wp:BackTitle>" +
                    "<wp:BackContent>" . $_POST["push_msg5"] . "</wp:BackContent>" +
                 "</wp:Tile> " .
              "</wp:Notification>";



    // Create request to send
    $r = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST["push_uri"]);
    curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 

    // add headers
    $httpHeaders=array('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'X-WindowsPhone-Target: token',
                    'Accept: application/*', 'X-NotificationClass: 1','Content-Length:'.strlen($tileMessage));
    curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeaders);

    // add message
    curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $tileMessage);

    // execute request
    $output = curl_exec($r);
    curl_close($r);
}
  ?>  

<form method="post" action="push2.php">
<h3>Push through php</h3>
<input type="text" name="push_uri" id="push_uri" placeholder="Push Uri" style="width:50%;padding:5px;" autofocus required/> <br><br>
<input type="text" name="push_msg0" id="push_msg0" placeholder="Background Image"  style="width:50%;padding:5px;" required/> <br><br>
<input type="text" name="push_msg1" id="push_msg1" placeholder="Count"  style="width:50%;padding:5px;" required/> <br><br>
<input type="text" name="push_msg2" id="push_msg2" placeholder="Title"  style="width:50%;padding:5px;" required/> <br><br>
<input type="text" name="push_msg3" id="push_msg3" placeholder="Back Background Image"  style="width:50%;padding:5px;" required/> <br><br>
<input type="text" name="push_msg4" id="push_msg4" placeholder="Back Title"  style="width:50%;padding:5px;" required/> <br><br>
<input type="text" name="push_msg5" id="push_msg5" placeholder="Back Content"  style="width:50%;padding:5px;" required/> <br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="push_action" value="1" />


<input type="submit" value="Push" style="width:50%;padding:5px;"/>
```

Comment: Can you put the full error text that you get? It seems some of the values you send is invalid. What kind of tile does the client application have (iconic, flip)? Did you check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267261/iconic-livetile-push-notification-via-php-results-in-payloadformaterror

Comment: @stipe The error message I got was ""The XML payload contains invalid or improperly formatted XML or the notification type specified in the header does not match the payload type used.  The channel has been closed.  Check your XML payload for errors and reopen the channel to obtain a new URI." I'm trying to update flip tiles. not iconic. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed out the Version=2.0, Tile ID & Tile template that caused it not to work.  Here's the updated for those 2 lines, after that I was able to update the tiles via push notifications.

```
"<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\" Version=\"2.0\">"
"<wp:Tile Id=\"/MainPage.xaml?Name=flip\" Template=\"FlipTile\">"
```